# How to enable highway for pedestrian routing?

Tags: here-api

I worked on a navigation app for a walking user only and I realized that some paths are automatically avoided and make the route longer.

For example, on:
[image: map showing two alternate routes for getting from destination A to B]

I calculate a route between 45.820548,1.229694 and 45.824472,1.227045, and the road in red (N520) is avoided. I would like to have the path in red instead of the blue one.

So I searched what make this red road avoided and on HERE Map Creator, I saw that this road is a "Highway" and pedestrian are not authorized to pass on this type of road. It seems logical that pedestrians can't go on the highway, but this road in my example has a sidewalk so pedestrians should be able to navigate on it.

Do I need to change or create a new path on HERE Map Creator to solve the problem, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I think the "simple but slower" way would be to report a correction in HERE Map Creator and let it be validated by HERE Experts and then once it gets approved the Route would be calculated by the API correctly. However this approach will take sometime as the validation process has some delays (upto months in my expirence) usually.

Another "faster but complex" approach could be to use the HERE Fleet Telematics API and override the road attributes in a custom "Overlay" and then use the HERE Fleet Telematics API (instead of HERE Routing API ) along with the custom Overlay to calculate a route. The API itself is not so trivial to use (in my opnion), some examples are available here though : https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/topics/custom-routes.html